# WMI Export-CSV creates System.String for IP Addresses (dynamically selecting objects)

Tags: powershell

This code, when exported to CSV causes a "System.String[]" output for IPAddress fields. I know the fix for this is to join the field but I am selecting objects dynamically based on user selected settings so I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

```
$colItems = GWMI Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $PCname  -namespace "root\CimV2" -filter "IpEnabled = TRUE" 

###Define Settings Array
$settings_array = @()
Foreach ($objItem in $chklstGetMIPRet.CheckedItems)
{$settings_array += [String]$objItem}
#####

###Export to CSV
$colItems | Select-Object -Property $settings_array | export-  csv "$ScriptDir\Exports\$Outputfile" -NoType
```

$chklstGetMIPRet is a check list box that the user selects which classes of the WMI they would like displayed. $chklstGetMIPRet.CheckedItems contains all of the currently checked values in that check list box. So the foreach goes through and for each of the checked items add that value to $settings_array

EDIT:

This code works:

```
$prop_list = @{"MACAddress" = "MACAddress"}
$prop_list += @{"Caption" = "Caption}
$prop_list += @{"IPAddress" = $colItems.IPAddress -join ', '}

Foreach ($objItem in $chklstGetMIPRet.CheckedItems)
 {$exp_settings_array += $prop_list[$objItem]}

$colItems | Select-Object -Property $exp_settings_array | export-csv "$ScriptDir\Exports\$Outputfile" -NoType
```

Except when it exports, i get Caption and MACaddress correctly with labels but IPAddress simply exports the Actual IP to the top line with no label.

Comment: $chklstGetMIPRet is a check list box that the user selects which classes of the WMI they would like displayed. $chklstGetMIPRet.CheckedItems contains all of the currently checked values in that check list box. So the foreach goes through and for each of the checked items add that value to $settings_array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how you will need to implement this, but the root cause is that the field actually is an array of strings. This will work to give you an example:

```
$colItems = GWMI Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $PCname  -namespace "root\CimV2" -filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"
$settings_array = @()
$settings_array += 'DHCPEnabled'
$settings_array += @{n='IPAddress';e={$_.IPAddress -join ', '}}
$colItems | Select-Object -Property $settings_array
```

Obviously you will have to work that into the $chklstGetMIPRet.CheckedItems property in your code.

In your case, I would suggest having a hashtable that has keys that match the checkeditems and values that express what exactly to add to the property array for that item. So for example (untested since I don't have the time to mock up a form to test it):

```
$ph = @{n='IPAddress';e={$_.IPAddress -join ', '}
$propertyLookup = @{'DHCPEnabled' = 'DHCPEnabled';
                        'IPAddress' = $ph
                       }
```

That gives you the lookup hash then in the foreach where you build the property array:

```
$settings_array += $propertyLookup[$objItem]
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. `$settings_array = @() Foreach ($objItem in $chklstGetMIPRet.CheckedItems) $settings_array += @{n='$objItem';e={$_.$objItem -join ', '}}}`

Comment: What is $chklstGetMIPRet.CheckedItems? where does it come from? What does it hold? Please ad the information to your question.

Comment: added as a comment to my question

Comment: So what is the error? What is the actual Type for the object? What are it's properties? You need to do a little of the work here yourself. I'm just trying to give guidance. As I said, I don't have the time to build a form just to test this code.

Comment: Even without the form it says the hash literal is incomplete. If I try it within the form it gives me an error that it's missing an '=' after the key in hash literal. To me it just doesn't look like you can assign a value like that in a hash table...

It works fine if I don't include the lines with the @{n='IPAddress';e={$_.IPAddress -join ', '};

Comment: This compiles and runs:  $propertyLookup = @{"IPAddress" = $_.IPAddress -join ', ';}, but still gives me the System.String output in the csv.

Comment: Try it the way that I have it now.

Comment: Isn't this trying to store a hash table inside a hash table?
Should it be something more like
`$propertyLookup = @{'DHCPEnabled' = 'DHCPEnabled';
                        'IPAddress' = $_.IPAddress -join ', '}`